# Using slide toggle on a multilevel list, level 2 will act as if level 1 has been clicked

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm trying to do a multi level navigation using lists, but when I toggle the first level and click the second to reveal the third level, the second level toggles. Wonder if there was a fix to this?

My code so far:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".listSchool").click(function(){
    $(this).children("ul").children().slideToggle();
});

$(".listClass").click(function(){
    $(this).children("ul").children().slideToggle();
});
});
```

Comment: what is your mean about the first and second level...?

Comment: <ul>
  <li>FirstLevel<ul>
         <li>SecondLevel<ul>
               <li>ThirdLevel</li>
               <li>ThirdLevel</li>
         <li>SecondLevel<ul>
               <li>ThirdLevel</li>
               <li>ThirdLevel</li>
         </ul></li>
</ul>

Bah that didn't format so well, what I mean is lists, within lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to stop event bubbling.

Basically when you click an inner element, the parent is also clicked. If that parent has an event bound for clicks, it gets fired.

Using `event.stopPropagation();` should prevent this.

[jQuery API - event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".listSchool, .listClass").click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
     $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
   });
});
```

Comment: I read the article and this seems like it should be the correct answer, but for some reason this has now stopped anything from happening at all.

Comment: Forget that, that was a silly mistake on my part, however what is happening now when I click the first <li> then the sublist AND subsublist is toggled. These lists are going to be quite large so I don't want them to all expand immediately.

Comment: @RichieVikinglordTerry create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see exactly what is happening.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qMrLW/1/ - sorry about the horrible HTML formatting, I got it from the firefox view source of my site because the list is getting it's info from a database and the PHP is making the HTML ugly.

Comment: @RichieVikinglordTerry look at this http://jsfiddle.net/qMrLW/2/ - FYI, I changed the css to hide only sub lists (ul ul).